# Can't define runtime of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, runtime, heap, binary-heap

I have one algorithm here.

[Click here to check algorithm image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WvOi.png)

What it does, it traverse an array and find 3 largest values and return their sum.
For example, an array [1,2,3,4,5] will return 12 (3+4+5=12).

The algorithm in the image says it is O(nlogk). But that is what I cannot understand.

**Followings is my perspective about first for loop in the image:**

Heap's method "insert()" and "deleteMin()", they both takes O(logn). So in the first for loop, it makes O(2*logn) by adding their runtime, which is simply O(logn). Since first for loop iterates for all element in the array, so total runtime of first for loop is O(nlogn).

**Following is my perspective about 2nd while loop in the image:**

From the previous for loop, we have deleted some of minimum values if h.size() > k. So the number of values in the heap is currently k. "sum=sum+h.min()" takes O(logn) because searching minimum value in heap takes O(logn) if I know correctly, and "h.deleteMin()" also takes O(logn) because it has to search again and delete. So is O(2*logn) by adding their runtime, which is simply O(logn). Since we iterate this while loop for only k times because there are k numbers of elements, so 2nd while loops result in O(k*logn)

So we have O(nlogn) from first for loop, and O(k*logn) from 2nd while loop. It is obvious that O(nlogn) is greater than O(k*logn) since k is some constant. Thus this algorithm ends in being O(nlogn) at the end.

**But the answer says it is "O(nlogk)" instead of "O(nlogn)".**

Can you explain the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption about insert() and deletemin() runtime takes O(log n) is the not correct. The 'n' in O(log n) represents the no.of elements in heap. In this case it is k.

Hence, for the first loop - you have O(2*logk) for every element and a total will have O(n*logk) and 2nd loop - O(k*logk)
Together the total complexity can be defines as O(n*logk)

Answer (score 1):

Operations on heap take `O(log(size_of_heap))`. In case of this algorithm heap size is `k` (excluding first several iterations).

So we get `O(total_number_of_elements*log(size_of_heap))=O(n*log(k))`.